# Using Eclipse to find where console output code exists

Tags: eclipse

so I'm not sure if you can even do this but I'm wondering if there is some way of finding where a `System.out.println()` console result would be within the code without needing to scroll through and find the specific `System.out.println()` code.

Answer (score 1):

Menu *Search* → *Java...* → *Search string:* `println(*)` → *Search For:*   ◉ *Method* → *Limit to:*   ◉ *All occurrences* → <kbd>Search</kbd>